# How to find document in Mongodb by _id In PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

$question_list = $this->collection->find(array('_id'=>$question_id));

collection has been defined as a collection,but the list is null,I'm sure the question_id is exist in the collection ,it is the _id

Comment: I have disolved it:
   $question_list = $this->collection->find(array('_id'=>new MongoId($question_id)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$question_list = $this->collection->find(array('_id'=> new MongoId($question_id)));
```

I recently started to use numeric primary keys in my projects. It's much easier to handle in combination with PHP / JS.